# Framelayout in CoordinatorLayout with Recycleview add app:layout_behavior doesn't work

Tags: android

I have two XML, `education_fragment` will add in `navigation_drawer_layout`.

I use the mother container by `CoordinatorLayout`,and reference some solution to put the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in `Framelayout`.

It's still not working.

Do i missed something?

navigation_drawer_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

education_fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".SubpagesLayout.Education"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/educationRecycleView"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I take some advice and change like this , my Framelayout can show under Toolbar,it's working now. here is my change code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think that `education_fragment` is correct. `<view` is not a valid tag, as far as I know.

Comment: Also, `DrawerLayout` is meant to be the root view. It cannot be inside a CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: <view> is valid, but on top of that, layout_behavior must be set on direct children of CoordinatorLayout, not any child in the hierarchy.

Comment: @natario I know `<View>` is a valid, base `View.java` class, but when I see `<view ...  class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`, and `TODO: Update blank fragment layout`, that makes me think a Fragment used to be there, and that is not how a RecyclerView is declared.

Comment: @cricket_007 no that’s really a lowercase view, it is meant to be used with custom Views declared as static inner classes (that have $s in their names, like com.package.OuterClass$InnerView). Not needed with Recycler for sure though.

Comment: Well I'm not sure the place of doubt,my education layout java is like this :public class Education extends Fragment,it shows list success and i can change the fragment in framelayout.
I take the advice to exchange the place between Drawerlayout and CoordinatorLayout.
The layout shows error like the drawer will open when app starting and framelayout will disappear some views.

Comment: @徐博俊 put also the FrameLayout outside of AppBarLayout, so it becomes a direct child of CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: When i change the FrameLayout outside of AppBarLayout,it will cover to my Tablayout,how do i avoid it ?  i try any places can't fix it

Comment: I correct. it's toolbar not tablayout

Comment: thanks @natario and cricker_007 , the direct place is important, i fix my problem now, trully thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to answer your own question below so others can see full solution